# Unable to use displacy(spacy lib) in VS Code

Tags: nlp, spacy, displacy

Nothing shows up on terminal while using displacy in V.S Code
I have created a  on virtual env in VS code without jupyter

I have tried both the .serve and .render methods
.serve method redirects me to a external browser
[Site not available msg keeps showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMEyL.png)
code for .serve

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep")
```

while render method just doesn't display anything

(Is there a way to do this without creating a env in/using jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample works perfectly in my local machine. Couple of points that could help you:

- Check the console if you are able to run it properly, After running your code, In my case my console/terminal was was showing:

```bash
Using the 'dep' visualizer
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:3000 ...
```

- If you run into issues like port is already in use, then you can explicitly specify the port. For example I specified 3000 port to use:

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep", port=3000) # port=3000 specifies the port
```

- You can access via browser by visiting `http://0.0.0.0:3000` or `http://localhost:3000` (sometimes `localhost` works while `0.0.0.0` may not)

Comment: Yea it worked in localhost..any idea why ```0.0.0.0``` doesn't work?

Comment: I think accordingly to this https://superuser.com/questions/1755409/is-the-definition-of-0-0-0-0-consistent-across-os seems like windows shows it as invalid address. I tested it on macOS and it was working